# Inequality regarding summation and min function

Tags: inequality, summation

I need your expertise in solving the following problem:

Let $a_i,b_i \in [0,\infty)$ for each $i \in [n]$, then it is known that the following applies:
$$ \min\left\lbrace \sum_{i=1}^n a_i , \sum_{j=1}^n b_j \right\rbrace \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \min\left\lbrace a_i , \sum_{j=1}^n b_j \right\rbrace $$
Is the following true, and if so can it be proven:
$$ \min\left\lbrace \sum_{i=1}^n a_i , \sum_{j=1}^n b_j \right\rbrace \leq \text{const}(n) \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \min\left\lbrace a_i , b_i \right\rbrace $$

Please advise and thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $a_i$ large for odd $i$ and small for even $i$, while $b_i$ is small for odd $i$ and large for even $i$. For $n > 1$, given any $c_n$, you can choose $a_i$ and $b_i$ so that $\min \Bigl\{\sum a_i, \sum b_i\Bigr\} > c_n \sum \min \{ a_i,b_i\}$.

Comment: so for every $c_n$ the above applies?

Comment: No, look at the sense of the inequality. If $n > 1$, for every $c_n$, you can find sequences so that your inequality does _not_ hold.

Comment: Oh ok. Then does the following apply following:
$$ \min\left\lbrace \sum_{i=1}^n a_i , \max_{j \in [n]} b_j \right\rbrace \leq \text{const}(n) \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \min\left\lbrace a_i , b_i \right\rbrace ?$$

Comment: Except for $n = 1$, you can always arrange it so that $\min \{a_i,b_i\} = 0$ for all $i$, but the left hand side is strictly positive. Even if you disallow $0$ as a value, you can still get as close as you want on the right.